# How to add Thread Name to each request context to Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

In creating a python thread with name, we can do it by

```
t = threading.Thread(target=func,name="my_thread")
```

In flask, each request spawns its own thread holding the context until the process is completed. How do i assign dynamic name to these threads being created by flask?

Comment: what do you want to do with thread naming?

Comment: I would like to add names to threads to easily identify which context/request/threads to narrow down when debugging. I know there are some other ways to debug, but again just wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: I was doing this by using unique identifier for each request, I can show you if you want

Comment: Can you please share how you did it?

Comment: i'll put on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the quick and easy solution to this.
Within the flask's api context somewhere you can get the current thread and rename it:

```
t = threading.current_thread()
t.name = "renamed_thread"
```

This way, i can better see in vscode debugging window the threads spawn for each API calls without inspecting them individually...

Answer (score 0):

can try this one [chain-logging](https://pypi.org/project/chain-logging/0.1.1/)

```
from flask import Flask
from chain_logging.flask import setup_chained_logger, logger

app = Flask(__name__)

setup_chained_logger(app)

@app.get("/home")
def home():
    logger.info("this is a trial 1")
    logger.error("this is a trial 2")
    logger.warning("this is a trial 3")
    logger.critical("this is a trial 3")
    return {"status": "welcome home!"}
```

every time you make request, you;ll have different id